# How to set the same outptut extent for plotRGB and plot?

Tags: r, plot, raster

Generating a plot using `plot` and `plotRGB` doesn't give the same outptut extent . I would like to have the same extent output for [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3kot.png) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJAHP.png).

```
# generate red, green, blue random 10 by 10 matrix
r <- g <- b <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
values(r) <- runif(ncell(r))
values(g) <- runif(ncell(r))
values(b) <- runif(ncell(r))

rgb = rgb<-stack(r*255,g*255,b*255)

# plot red
plot(r,legend=F)
# plot RGB
plotRGB(rgb)
```

[image: Result from plot the red band] [image: Result from the plotRGB]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `raster::plot` wants to add a legend to the plot, so it saves some space at the right hand side, while `plotRGB` just takes the full extent.

You can work around this by adding the rasters to an existing plot:

```
library(raster)

# generate red, green, blue random 10 by 10 matrix
r <- g <- b <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
values(r) <- runif(ncell(r))
values(g) <- runif(ncell(r))
values(b) <- runif(ncell(r))

rgb = rgb<-stack(r*255,g*255,b*255)
par(mfrow=c(2,1))

plot(c(-180,180),c(-90,90), type='n', axes=F, xlab='', ylab='')
plotRGB(rgb,add=T)

plot(c(-180,180),c(-90,90), type='n', axes=F, xlab='', ylab='')
plot(r,add=T, legend=F)
```

Comment: @ koekenbakker: indeed, you're right, it works with what you've proposed but I can't remove the xlabel and ylabel (xlab is c(-180,180) and ylab is c(-90,90)) using xlab=NULL and ylab=NULL. Any idea of how to remove them?

Comment: Yes, `''` instead of `NULL`:)